# xprivacy and Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge, orbot, pluggable-transports

Is anyone else having connection issues using Tor to connect to any variation on xprivacy.eu. (e.g. https, www.xprivacy.eu, xprivacy.edu and just to see if I'm crazy the insecure http xprivacy.eu)

I'm using bridges and obfs3 and have tried on both Android and PC.  Tor Browser and Orweb seems to otherwise be working fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Maybe they are blocking tor (intentionally or unintentionally). You could try filing an issue via github: https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy/